# connect real decvice to localhost

Tags: node.js, flutter, flutter-dependencies

i want to connect my real device to localhost to post and get data from api

```
var url = Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.13:3000/api/signup");
var response = await http.post(
  url,
  body: json.encode({
    "name": user.name,
    "email": user.email,
    "password": user.password,
    "address": user.address,
    "type": user.type,
    "_id": user.id,
    "__v": user.v,
  }),


);
```

when i press signup he gives me nothing and no errors appears
I'm using my ipv4 address

Answer (score 0):

did you give internet permission to your app?
like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="...">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <!-- Add 
 this -->
</manifest>
```

Comment: yes i give internet permission

Comment: when i test api from postman it works and data is sent to server but when i send from mobile nothing appears

Comment: connect your device via USB cable and see debugging result where is your problem and if your code stops at some points or not, I don't think there other solution may help you

Comment: after a long time he gives me connection timed out

Answer (score 0):

There are possible reasons:

1- Make sure your **Mobile device** and **Development Machine** are in same network.

2- You need to make sure the Firewall on OS allow you to connect. Try Allowing Port **For Ubuntu** `$ sudo ufw allow 3000` **For Windows** [follow this article](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-open-port-windows-firewall)

Comment: both are connected to the same wifi network

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for **CORS** policy in your API.. make sure to add

```
var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
```

and also try pinging your phone from the PC.. and check if there is communication between the two devices